# Pass action to dispatch React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to pass an action as shown below to a component as props but am getting an error when doing so.

This seems to work fine:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import MyScheduleDispatch from './MyScheduleContext'


export default function generateShowItem({action}) {

  const dispatch = useContext(MyScheduleDispatch);

  const [isIconSolid, setIsIconSolid] = useState(false)

  function handleIconOnClick() {
    setIsIconSolid(!isIconSolid)
  }

  useEffect(() =>
    {
      if(isIconSolid) dispatch({ type: action, payload: item })
    },
    [isIconSolid]
  )

  const emptyIcon = <StarIconBorder onClick={handleIconOnClick} className={classes.star}></StarIconBorder>
  const solidIcon = <StarIconSolid onClick={handleIconOnClick} className={classes.star}></StarIconSolid>




  return (
    <div style={{position: 'relative'}} key={index}>
      {isIconSolid ? solidIcon : emptyIcon }
    </div>
  )
}
```

But when I try to pass the action (which is hard coded above as `"addItem"`, it throws an error

```
 useEffect(() =>
{
  if(isIconSolid) dispatch({ type: props.action, payload: item })
},
[isIconSolid]
)
```

Error:

```
Schedule.js:30 Uncaught Error
    at myScheduleReducer (Schedule.js:30)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:13247)
    at Object.useReducer (react-dom.development.js:13828)
    at useReducer (react.development.js:1467)
    at Schedule (Schedule.js:34)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:12939)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:14628)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15638)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19313)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19353)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19436)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20343)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20255)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20229)
    at requestWork (react-dom.development.js:20098)
    at commitPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:18796)
    at wrapped (scheduler-tracing.development.js:207)
    at flushFirstCallback (scheduler.development.js:107)
    at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:219)
    at MessagePort../node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js.channel.port1.onmessage (scheduler.development.js:611)
```

Note: I know that Redux is similar to this and uses "connect" to map dispatch to props, perhaps it has to do with something along those lines.. (just a thought)

https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Also, please paste the whole component

Comment: What's the name of the component above? Is it `Schedule.js` ?

Comment: If that's the only change I suggest adding `console.log(props.action)` just before `if(isIconSolid) dispatch({ type: props.action, payload: item })`.

Comment: @WillJenkins yes

Comment: It logs `undefined`

Comment: `generateShowItem({action})` already desturcted `props` and got `action` out of it. So inside `generateShowItem` you only has `action` and don't have `props` at all

Comment: Ok so if it's logging undefined you're not passing it in correctly. How are you using the component? (paste the jsx)

Answer (score 0):

try destructuring like this `const {dispatch} = useContext(myScheduleDispatch)`

Comment: well then that means that the problem lies in the way you set up your context not in the way you are dispatching